# How do I set the locale for an ASP.NET 5 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, locale, asp.net-core

I’m trying to do a blanket override of the host locale for an ASP.NET 5 web application. Most solutions refer to the `<globalization/>` web.config element, but this is IIS-specific and doesn't seem to fit the new ASP.NET model.

I tried:

```
app.Use(next => context => {
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU");
    return next(context);
});
```

This gets executed, but this doesn’t seem to have any effect on the request (maybe due to the extensive `Task`ing in the pipeline?) Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Where did you put this within the Configure method? The order is improtant!

Comment: Immediately before UseMvc. I originally had it after, and it never got hit :)

Comment: Just tested it and it works for me, how did you determine that it doesn't work?

Comment: I use a locale-sensitive format string and it returns the wrong value. If I put a breakpoint in the Razor view and check CurrentCulture, it returns the host culture. I’m using async actions if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is with the async controller. You should set the default culture to all threads instead:

```cs
app.Use(next => context => {
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU");

    return next(context);
});
```

You can actually just put these lines at the top of the Configure method:

```cs
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU");
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be ```CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-AU");```

Answer (score 5):

Localization is not yet ready for `ASP.NET 5` but you can take a look of what it could be on the [Damian Edwards's github](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/i18nStarterWeb)

**UPDATE** Tuesday, ‎July ‎21, ‎2015
‎
Localization will be in `beta6`. [See de the roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap)

**UPDATE** Dec. 27th, ‎2015

Localization is now available and we have sample in [aspnet/Localization](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization)