# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Date Posting Localisation Problem

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem sending a date in the format DD/MM/YY. This all works fine if I use the YY/MM/DD format, but my application is specific to the UK so I wish to only support this format.

My controller method begins like this:

```
public IActionResult Index(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
```

and the problem is that both date values are just coming in 0001-01-01 (DateTime.MinValue)

The controls are created in the .cshtml using the below.

```
@Html.TextBox("startDate", "", new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "dd/mm/yy" })
```

and this is wired up to a jQuery UI DatePicker. However I do not believe this is related to the issue as I said before, it works if I change to YY/MM/DD.

From findings on other questions on StackOverflow I have tried adding the following, but the issue still persists.

**Startup.cs:**

ConfigureServices Method:

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB");
    options.SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-GB") };
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
});
```

Configure Method:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-GB"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

I can confirm both of these are done before calling .AddMvc() / .UseMvc() as this was mentioned on another question.

I am a bit of a loss now, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is presented well; it's clear, gets down to the core issue, and effectively demonstrates your work. Thank you.

Comment: Here is exactly what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46051222/2568863

Comment: This one extended above answer: http://www.vickram.me/custom-datetime-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-web-api

Comment: @Dongdong Thank you, this was not a question I came across, I will implement this tomorrow.

Comment: @Dongdong This worked perfectly, thank you. If you want to post this as an answer instead of a comment, I can accept it.